# Vim function doesn't seem to be recognised

Tags: vim, command-line

I copied this in to `.vimrc`:

```
function! ClearAllButMatches()
  let old = @c
  let @c=""
  %s//\=setreg('C', submatch(0), 'l')/g
  %d _
  put c
  0d _
  let @c = old
endfunction
vnoremap <leader>c :<c-u>call g:ClearAllButMatches()<cr>
```

It doesn't seem to work. When I use `<leader>c`, I am getting this:

`E117: Unknown function: g:ClearAllButMatches`

Any ideas why its happening?

note:

1. I have sourced my .vimrc several times.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Vim: How to retain only the selected text in a file?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21523160/vim-how-to-retain-only-the-selected-text-in-a-file)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Remove `g:` from the mapping or add it to the function name

Comment: What did you try? I just deleted the `g:` from your mapping and everything worked just fine. Although you probably want to put a `e` flag at the end of your substitute command. And you might consider a different range that `%` (whole buffer).

Comment: It looks as though the function and the mapping are defined in the same file.  To check that, try `:verbose map <leader>c` and `:verbose function ClearAllButMatches` and read carefully the "Last set from" lines.