# Vim: How to retain only the selected text in a file?

Tags: regex, vim

I tried to use the following but somehow using the short cut results in the error: `E117: Unknown function: g:ClearAllButMatches`. I even tried to type in: `call g:ClearAllButMatches()` but still no use, the same error. Any ideas to get it to work or any other solution for this?

```
function! ClearAllButMatches()
  let old = @c
  let @c=""
  %s//\=setreg('C', submatch(0), 'l')/g
  %d _
  put c
  0d _
  let @c = old
endfunction
vnoremap <leader>c :<c-u>call g:ClearAllButMatches()<cr>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just remove the `g:`:

```
vnoremap <leader>c :<c-u>call ClearAllButMatches()<cr>
```

Comment: Thanks! Issues of a total newbie :D